# How to use json-server | Getting 404 for local db.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, rest, json-server

I'm pretty sure doing everything correctly. I'm using these version:

```
"axios": "^0.24.0",
"json-server": "^0.17.0",
```

I've followed the official doc. I've `db.json` in the root folder itself.

```
{
"users": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Username": "mike",
      "Password": "User1Password"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Username": "robert",
      "Password": "User2Password"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm running `json-server` with this command:
`json-server --watch db.json --port 4000`

Whenever I hit `http://localhost:4000/users` I'm served with this:

```
  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:4000/posts
  http://localhost:4000/comments
  http://localhost:4000/profile

  Home
  http://localhost:4000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...

  GET /users 404 4.800 ms - 2
```

But rest of the end points like:

```
http://localhost:4000/posts
http://localhost:4000/comments
http://localhost:4000/profile
```

are working absolutely fine. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to @user2740650** 
You said db.json is in src folder. What matters is that it's in the same folder where you started the server. It sounds like it created a default db.json somewhere else and is using that.

**Second Scenario**
move your db.json file into the Public folder and calling it by: axios.get('db.json') .then(//...)

Comment: can you plz look into this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777098/react-and-json-server-getting-request-failed-with-status-code-500

Comment: Not found #deadlink

Comment: yeah, i removed the question because i restarted the server and it started working as expected. thanks for showing interest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Copying my own comment to an answer as requested:

You said `db.json` is in the `src` folder. What matters is that it's in the same folder where you started the server. It sounds like it created a default `db.json` somewhere else and is using that.

Comment: can you plz look into this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777098/react-and-json-server-getting-request-failed-with-status-code-500

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Look at your JSON-server console output for the path to the version of db.json it is loading when you start the server. Use that file as your working copy. For me, the path was in the topmost folder, parent folder of src and public.

Otherwise it creates db.json in that path with the default data:

```
"posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
],
"comments": [
     { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
    ],
  "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. There was another service "OneApp.IGCC.WinService.exe" was listening on port 5000(on which I ran the json server). I changed the port json server was running on. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the rest of the end points work is because when you install the json-sever it adds a default db.json inside your public folder having the following endpoints:

```html
http://localhost:4000/posts
http://localhost:4000/comments
http://localhost:4000/profile
```

Default db.json will look like

```js
{
    "posts": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "json-server",
        "author": "typicode"
    }],
    "comments": [{
        "id": 1,
        "body": "some comment",
        "postId": 1
    }],
    "profile": {
        "name": "typicode"
    }
  }
```

You can remove this data and add users collection as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I'm my case I wasn't specifying the db route which was in a folder named database,
for example:
json-server --watch db.json
should be:
json-server --watch database/db.json